# Logstash behind the proxy doesn't work

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy, logstash

I'm trying to launch few Logstash instances behind the proxy.

I'm using nginx, but HAProxy is an option as well.

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream streams {
        server logstash_ip:5044;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
            proxy_pass http://streams;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        }
    }
}
```

`logstash_ip` is an alias, it is resolvable.

The problem is that when I'm pushing some logs directly to the logstash - everything is ok.

When I'm pushing logs through the Nginx it fails:

1. Navigating Nginx with port gives me 502 Gateway error
2. Logstash logs

   Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error

Answer (score 4):

> Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error

Which is true, as the `lumberjack` protocol is not one based on `http`, which is what Nginx is expecting in your configuration. I suggest trying [a `stream { }` block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/) instead for nginx, as that's designed for TCP-protocols.

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 80
  }
  upstream stream_backend {
    server logstash_ip:5044
  }
}
```

Comment: missing ` proxy_pass stream_backend;` inside stream/server block